# How to Include an App.Config file of a Class Library in the Web Publish release package

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have ran into a scenario where I have added an **App.Config** file in a **Class Library** which I am referencing from my **ASP.NET MVC project**.

Now while publishing my Web project I can only see the DLL of the class library in the Bin folder but not the App.Config of the same. Is there any way to include that in the Web publish.

Thanks

Comment: The configuration system only reads from the executing assembly's config. You have to put the settings from the library into the main application's config file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler to copy these files to the output directory. To do so, select the `app.config` from the solution explorer and hit `F4` for `properties` and select **Copy Always** like the below example

[image]

Comment: Did that but that doesn't include the same while publishing the web project.

Comment: So you want your app settings. Json on the env variables? Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Your class library shouldnt be using the app.config file. Instead the driver application or consuming application should be having a single app.config and should feed this dll with parameters.

This will also help your application being more SOLID. Your class library should be doing single job. Reading from a app.config file adds a second responsibility.

Also, class library not reading from the app.config file make your class library loosely coupled and it can be taken anywhere.

Comment: True, but due to some constraints i had to use the same, i also tried resource file (.resx) but again i am not able to produce them as a single file while publishing my web project. Any suggestions.